# VBA - Find a window handle knowing its caption, class and its owner

Tags: vba, api, findwindow

It should be easy but it doesn't work in the way I imagined...
It is about "Print Merge Wizard" window of Corel DRAW.
I can find the window with Spy++, its Caption and its Class. **I cannot find its handle using API**.
Using FindWindow I can only obtain the main Corel Window:

```
TxtHwnd = FindWindow("CorelDRAW18", vbNullString)
```

When I try the same way, using the caption and the class, it cannot return the handle:

```
hMerge = FindWindow("#32770 (Dialog)", "Print Merge Wizard")
```

I tried using of FindWindowEx in the next way, but without success:

```
TxtHwnd = FindWindow("CorelDRAW18", vbNullString): Debug.Print TxtHwnd
hMerge = FindWindowEx(TxtHwnd, ByVal CLngPtr(0), "#32770 (Dialog)", "Print Merge Wizard")
```

I also tried to iterate through all open windows using:

```
    Sub ListWins(Optional Title = "*XYZ*", Optional Class = "*")
    Dim hWndThis As Long
    hWndThis = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)
    While hWndThis
        Dim sTitle As String, sClass As String
        sTitle = Space$(255)
        sTitle = Left$(sTitle, GetWindowText(hWndThis, sTitle, Len(sTitle)))
        sClass = Space$(255)
        sClass = Left$(sClass, GetClassName(hWndThis, sClass, Len(sClass)))
        If sTitle Like Title And sClass Like Class Then
            Debug.Print sTitle, sClass
            Stop
        End If
        hWndThis = GetWindow(hWndThis, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        Debug.Print sTitle, sClass, hWndThis
    Wend 
End Sub
```

Calling the function like this:

```
ListWins "Print Merge Wizard", "#32770 (Dialog)"
```

The window in discussion is not between the ones showed by the code...
Looking into Spy++ window properties I can see the Print Merge Wizard is not a Corel child window. It just shows Corel like being its owner...

**Knowing all that, in which way do you think I can catch the Print Merge Wizard Window handler**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the [FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) documentation: "This function does not search child windows."  Use [FindWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa) instead.

Comment: I tried it only after FindWindowEx did not do the job. Ai tested FindWindoEx, too. It is written in my initial post. Ins Spy++ the window I look for it does not appear as being Corel Child. Corel window appears like being its owner...

Comment: Well *not* using `FindWindowEx` is certainly not the solution. Does it show up in the output of `ListWins` when you use `FindWindowEx`?

Comment: It strangely works using FindWindow without class name, even it was correct:     hwndWiz = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Print Merge Wizard") returns the right handler..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strangely works using `FindWindow` without class name, even if the class name was correct:

`hwndWiz = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Print Merge Wizard")` returns the right handler.

Answer (score 1):

The class name is not "#32770 (Dialog)" it is just "#32770", the " (Dialog)" part is appended by Spy++.

If the caption has a leading "&" it must be kept in the argument passed to the API function.